# basic Siemens CNC parser in python not detecting syntax errors

Tags: python, parsing, syntax, siemens, cnc

Hi I'm trying to build a parser in python that parses siemens cnc for a project and i have got it to detect some syntax errors but others it just ignores

this is my code:

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas, nums, Suppress, Group, LineEnd, OneOrMore, restOfLine, ZeroOrMore,                    ParseException

integer = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda t: int(t[0]))
float_number = Word(nums + ".").setParseAction(lambda t: float(t[0]))
identifier = Word(alphas, alphas + nums + "_")
  
input_text = """
G95 X10 Y20
G02 X30 Y40 I5 J5
G0 Z5
;comment
M03
G01 X15 Y25 H10
;comment here too

"""
  
g_code = (Suppress("G") + integer).setParseAction(lambda t: f"G{t[0]:02d}")
m_code = (Suppress("M") + integer).setParseAction(lambda t: f"M{t[0]:02d}")

x_coordinate = Group("X" + float_number)
y_coordinate = Group("Y" + float_number)
z_coordinate = Group("Z" + float_number)
i_coordinate = Group("I" + float_number)
j_coordinate = Group("J" + float_number)
code = (g_code | m_code) + ZeroOrMore(x_coordinate | y_coordinate | z_coordinate | i_coordinate |              j_coordinate)("params") + restOfLine

comment = Suppress(";" + restOfLine)
siemens_cnc_grammar = OneOrMore(Group(code | comment))

try:
    parsed_result = siemens_cnc_grammar.parseString(input_text, parseAll=True)

    for line in parsed_result:
        if len(line) > 0 and line[0] != ";":
            command = line[0]
            print("Command:", command)

            for param_value in line.params:
                param_key = param_value[0]
                param_val = param_value[1]
                print("Parameter:", param_key, "=", param_val)
            print()

except ParseException as e:
    print("Syntax Error:")
    print("Line:", e.lineno)
    print("Context:", e.markInputline())
```

the H10 is an example syntax error I added to test it but it just ignores it and doesn't pick up on it. i tried using chatgpt/some ai for help as im very new to building the parser but it just made everything worse

Comment: Have you ever thought about using [Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)? I've already made a parser for CNC but in C#, handling errors using Regex and it worked perfectly.